# Semantic-UI dynamic popup not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, semantic-ui

```
   var val = '124';

        function imagepop(nval) {
          val = nval;
        }
        $(document)
                .ready(function () {
                    $('.ui.selection.dropdown').dropdown();
                    $('.ui.menu .ui.dropdown').dropdown({
                        on: 'hover'
                    });

                    $('#'+val).popup({
                        popup: $('.fluid.popup'),
                        on: 'click'
                    });
                });
```

Im trying to popup dynamic content coming from database HTML code as below

```
<div class="extra">
        <div id="<?php echo$row['idproperty']; ?>" class="ui more primary button"  onclick="imagepop(<?php echo$row['idproperty']; ?>)">
        More
       </div>

      <div class="ui fluid popup top left transition hidden" >
      <p><b>Description</b><?php echo$row['description']; ?></p>
      <div class="ui three column center aligned grid">
      <div class="column"> </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

`idproperty` is some numbers getting from database i need to show each data in popups please help me to fix this

Comment: When will the function `imagepop(nval)` get called? Does the default value assigned to `val` above has any meaning?

Comment: its calling from onclick('125'); like that

Answer (score 0):

the function at `$(document).ready` is called before the function `imagepop(nval)` which assignes the value of `idprperty` to `val`.
The function at `$(document).ready` is called only once, when the document is done loading, that means that this part of the code:

```
$('#'+val).popup({
    popup: $('.fluid.popup'),
    on: 'click'
});
```

Will not be called when `val` gets the new value, the one originated from `idproperty`.

Move that part of the code to the end of your `imagepop(navl)` function, that should probably fix your issue.

If you still want to have this part of the code run immidiatly as the page loads, you will need to have the true value of `idproperty` ready to be right then. One way to do this is to include a hideen input field in your HTML and have the PHP feed it the value as a default, and then read this value from your js in the `$(document).ready` function:

in your html:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="idproperty" name="idproperty" value="<?php echo $row['idproperty']; ?>">
```

in your `$(document).ready` function:

```
val = $(idproperty).val();
$('#'+val).popup({ //... rest of your code here
```

Comment: is their any way to pop up this with out in $(document).ready ?

Comment: Yes, you will just have to make sure that `val` gets updated before, or exactly when the document is ready. One way to do it is to use a hidden input field in your HTML that is fed `idproperty` as its default vlue using PHP. I will edit my answer to include this in more detail.

Comment: but i need to change it dynamically when i click the button

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite got it. If you want to change it dynamically when you click something, then the first solution should work for you, just move the part of the code that does the pop up to the end of your `imagepop(nval)` function, and it should work.  As for you question in the first comment, I don't see a reason why you would need the `$(document).ready` at all for this matter.